# Encapsulate table with view

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-design, view, design-pattern

I need to change the order of columns in my table (Oracle and SQL Server). Reason is that some of our software calls `select *` and `insert` without specifying columns. Refactoring will be too expensive so I need to solve it on the database level.

My idea is to create a new view which will encapsulate the table and just change the order of columns. Current table will be renamed and new view will have the original name. I found here that encapsulating a table with a view is some kind of database design pattern.

Here are my questions:

- Do I lose performance when I encapsulate a table with a view and call the view only?
- Do you see any risk with naming the view (there will not be V_ prefix)?
- Do you see any other advantage / disadvantage in encapsulating a table with a view?

Comment: some information is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237601/sql-server-2005-wrapping-tables-by-views-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

- A view increases the overhead but if the view only contains a select with a different column ordering, the overhead will not be noticeable.
- You can also rebuild the table with the column order you want (a rather expensive one time operation)
- Most people agrees that views should follow the same naming standard as tables (i.e. no V_, or any other, special prefix)

Having said that, software should almost never do selects or inserts, without specifying the columns.

Comment: +1 for rebuilding. I've never gotten the impression of a consensus on view naming conventions, though the implications tend to be very dependent on the environment you're working in.